# Create Rewrite rule in htaccess for a user profile

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

So I have a dilemma..

Can't figure out how to rewrite this URL to THIS URL:

URL=www.EXAMPLE.com/users/USERNAME

THIS URL= www.EXAMPLE.com/USERNAME

This isn't my first time using Stack Overflow, but this is my first time actually needing an account to find my answer. I will Thank accordingly.

Thanks,
Nick

EDIT:

```
    RewriteRule ^user/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

But I get a 404 page, weird I say.

The page redirects successfully, but with a 404 instead.

HTACCESS as follows:

```
   ## Mod_rewrite in use.

   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteRule ^user/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]

   ## Begin - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.
   # If you experience problems on your site block out the operations listed below
   # This attempts to block the most common type of exploit `attempts` to Joomla!
   #
   # Block out any script trying to base64_encode data within the URL.
   RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
   # Block out any script that includes a <script> tag in URL.
   RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
   # Block out any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL.
   RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
   # Block out any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL.
   RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
   # Return 403 Forbidden header and show the content of the root homepage
   RewriteRule .* index.php [F]
   #
   ## End - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.

   ## Begin - Custom redirects
   #
   # If you need to redirect some pages, or set a canonical non-www to
   # www redirect (or vice versa), place that code here. Ensure those
   # redirects use the correct RewriteRule syntax and the [R=301,L] flags.
   #

   ## End - Custom redirects

   ##
   # Uncomment following line if your webserver's URL
   # is not directly related to physical file paths.
   # Update Your Joomla! Directory (just / for root).
   ##

   # RewriteBase /

   ## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section.
   #
   RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
   #
   # If the requested path and file is not /index.php and the request
   # has not already been internally rewritten to the index.php script
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
   # and the request is for something within the component folder,
   # or for the site root, or for an extensionless URL, or the
   # requested URL ends with one of the listed extensions
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /component/|(/[^.]*|\.(php|html?|feed|pdf|vcf|raw))$ [NC]
   # and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical file
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   # and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical folder
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   # internally rewrite the request to the index.php script
   RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
   #
   ## End - Joomla! core SEF Section.
```

[UPDATE 4/08/13]
So after a while I have figured out that the only way an extension I am using works alongside Joomla! You need to use a separate extension called sh404sef to make this work. So in a nut shell, no use editing the HTACCESS file like I thought. Ended up spending the 40 bucks and it worked instantly. HAHA

Comment: did you tried anything as first step?

Comment: Yes, I have never had to do any rewriting personally. Most CMS come out of the box with it done for you or just by clicking a button. So I don't have much experience with it, but I have touched on it lightly in the past, just not in this way. So the as basic as the syntax might be to others, it isn't to me. So a basic example will get me on the right path and I can move forward from there if more help is needed.

Comment: see the [manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html) then try to search in stackoverflow to find more examples...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should answer your question

```
RewriteRule ^users/(.*)$ $1
```

Source: [.htaccess rewrite from subdirectory to root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8617799/htaccess-rewrite-from-subdirectory-to-root)

Comment: ok so... This IS the answer as I did plenty research and the actual rule works, well half way works..see new comment to post doitlikejustin

Comment: lol. that's a chunky .htaccess file :) glad you got it solved.

Answer (score 4):

A site i find useful with .htaccess url rewriting is: 
http://roshanbh.com.np/2008/03/url-rewriting-examples-htaccess.html

The example:

> Rewriting yoursite.com/user.php?username=xyz to yoursite.com/xyz
>
> Have you checked zorpia.com.If you type http://zorpia.com/roshanbh233
>   in browser you can see my profile over there. If you want to do the
>   same kind of redirection i.e http://yoursite.com/xyz to
>   http://yoursite.com/user.php?username=xyz then you can add the
>   following code to the .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ user.php?username=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ user.php?username=$1
```

So in your case you could go for:

```
RewriteRule ^users/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ user.php?username=$1
RewriteRule ^users/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ user.php?username=$1
```

Comment: I am looking at this site now and will post back with my results. Unfortunately I just realized the reputation system... So for now my thanks will be in comments!

Answer (score 0):

see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20610980/mod-rewrite-redirect-except-parked-domain
All www.primary.com go to www.primary.com/webtrees

```
Options -Indexes +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond $1 !^parked.com/
RewriteCond $1 !^piwik/
RewriteCond $1 !^wordpress/
RewriteCond $1 !^marker.htm
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/webtrees/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /webtrees/$1 [L]
```