# Url Routing in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

**My Laravel 5 Application is installed under the Directory Name:**

```
MyAccount
```

**I have following Url in the application:**

```
http://localhost:1234/laravel/MyAccount/public/allskills
```

**This is due to below route:**

```
Route::get("/allskills", "Skills\SkillsController@index");
```

**I am trying to change my Url to below:**

```
http://localhost:1234/allskills
```

**Question: Am I missing any setting in the above routing code ?**

Comment: You need to configure your web server in order to do that. Which web server are you using?

Comment: XAMPP server. On Window 8.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8617799/htaccess-rewrite-from-subdirectory-to-root this may help.

Comment: I think you installed your application in `htdocs\laravel\MyAccount`. If you want to have route like this you have to install your application in `htdocs` and avoid `/public` by editng you `.htaccess`. But this is bad idea to install any application in `htdocs`. You suppose to have more projects in that folder. Or you can use `homestead`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using laravel homestead. There are plenty of tutorials online (including screencasts on YouTube) that guide you through it. You can map a url like

"skills.app" to your MyAccount/public directory, so it can be accessed as

```
skills.app/allskills
```

If you want to find out more, check outt [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tbPGuikTzKk) short video series on YouTube, but of course if you don't want to go to these lengths you could use one of the answers already given.