# Rewrite root directory to subdirectory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, content-management-system

I am developing a website that runs a backend and a frontend out of two different directories.

- /frontend/
- /admin/

I would like to run the /frontend/ as the root whilst still running the /admin/ as it's own directory.

What do I need to write into the .htaccess to do this.

This is how my .htaccess file looks currently:

```
# Set the default handler.
DirectoryIndex index.php

# Prevent directory listing
Options -Indexes

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    ErrorDocument 404 /admin/404.php
</IfModule>
```

Any and all answers will be appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8617799/htaccess-rewrite-from-subdirectory-to-root

Answer (score 0):

Add this after `RewriteEngine On`:

```
# Redirect any requests within frontend/, removing frontend/
RewriteRule ^frontend/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
# Rewrite anything that is not in admin/ to frontend/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ frontend/$1 [L]
```

Be sure to update the base website URL on line 2.

Comment: for some reason I am receiving an error a 403 forbidden error at the root directory.

Comment: It sounds like there is no index file to serve from your `frontend`directory, which would give a 403 if you have autoindexing switched off. Is there an `index.php` file in `frontend`? It would only work with that now that you changed `DirectoryIndex` to only accept that.

Comment: Sorry, I had made two mistakes. Please update it with the new rules. Changing the `+` for a `*` on the second and last lines.

Comment: forbidden error has now gone - great! however I am still getting "192.168.33.10 redirected you too many times" any ideas?

Comment: I added the `L` flag to the last rule, which should hopefully stop that. Otherwise try changing it to `[END]`.

Comment: The END works however the root is being redirect to /admin/ - which makes sense according to your logic - how can we stop the root from redirecting within the above statement.

Comment: The logic above doesn't cause root to redirect to admin, it serves from /frontend/ but makes it look like it's from root. Unless it's /admin/ which it leaves alone. It also removes /frontend/ with an external redirect (bounces back to the browser) if an attempt is made to visit it directly. It sounds like either you need to clear your cache, or you have some other redirects causing this, or something in the root index script (/frontend/index.php) is causing the redirect.